# How to combine two query in a Single query ? can we do that?

Tags: apex, soql

How can we combine below two queries ? Can we do that ? If no, still I am ok. Just asking for curiosity perspectives.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM MilestoneType 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT MilestoneTypeId FROM CaseMilestone 
WHERE CaseId='500c0000009Ut1M')
```

The result of the above query:

```
    Id                  Name
1   557c0000000Cb8SAAS  XXXXXXXXX
2   557c0000000Cb8RAAS  YYYYYYYYY
3   557c0000000Cb9xAAC  ZZZZZZZZZ
4   557c0000000CbA7AAK  WWWWWWWWW
```

Another query is

```
SELECT CaseId,CompletionDate,CreatedDate,ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,IsCompleted,IsDeleted,IsViolated,MilestoneTypeId,StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone where MilestoneTypeId IN ('557c0000000Cb8SAAS','557c0000000Cb8RAAS','557c0000000Cb9xAAC','557c0000000CbA7AAK') 
and IsCompleted=true and CaseId='500c0000009Ut1M'
```

When I tried to do that, I get the below below error:

```
IN (SELECT MilestoneTypeId FROM CaseMilestone 
                                ^
ERROR at Row:3:Column:42
Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can combine both of the SOQL into one as follows:

```
SELECT CaseId,
    CompletionDate,
    CreatedDate,
    ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,
    IsCompleted,
    IsDeleted,
    IsViolated,
    MilestoneTypeId,
    MilestoneType.Name, 
    StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone  
WHERE IsCompleted=true 
and CaseId='<case id>'
AND MilestoneTypeId IN ('557c0000000Cb8SAAS','557c0000000Cb8RAAS','557c0000000Cb9xAAC','557c0000000CbA7AAK')
```

Now, if you want to display all the milestones information of the Case, then do not use the `MilestoneTypeId IN ('557c0000000Cb8SAAS','557c0000000Cb8RAAS','557c0000000Cb9xAAC','557c0000000CbA7AAK')`

That will be like this:

```
SELECT CaseId,
    CompletionDate,
    CreatedDate,
    ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,
    IsCompleted,
    IsDeleted,
    IsViolated,
    MilestoneTypeId,
    MilestoneType.Name, 
    StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone  
WHERE IsCompleted=true 
and CaseId='<case id>'
```

Comment: I have tried to give you efficient way to write SOQL to meet your use case, Ideally you want to display MilestoneTypeId and Name along with other details, so sub-query is not needed

Comment: is that my answer solves your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Add ID to Set, Then pass the Set to SOQL

```
  Set<String> ids=new Set<String>(); // or   Set<ID> 
    set.add('557c0000000Cb8SAAS');
    set.add('557c0000000Cb8RAAS');
    set.add('557c0000000Cb9xAAC');
    set.add('557c0000000CbA7AAK');


SELECT CaseId,CompletionDate,CreatedDate,ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,IsCompleted,IsDeleted,IsViolated,MilestoneTypeId,StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone where MilestoneTypeId IN : ids 
and IsCompleted=true and CaseId='500c0000009Ut1M'
```

Below SOQL Return 2 field value of **CaseMilestone ID** and **MilestoneTypeId**, so directly you can't pass **milestoneTyleId** as a subQuery for **MilestoneType** object

```
SELECT MilestoneTypeId FROM CaseMilestone WHERE CaseId='500c0000009Ut1M'
```